# How to add alias / display name along with email address in Specify From Address(es) at case layout?

Tags: email, email2case, quickaction, casefeed

I was able to add email addresses in case layout to default 'From' address when sending an email from Case Quick Action

But how to add alias in each email address?
Or is it possible to fill 'Specify From Address(es)' at case layout -> feed view by filling **Organization Wide Address email members**?

I tried to putting manually like below:
[image]

But it shows like this:
[image]

Can I add alias to sender case email quick action?